# why do not Redis provide a batch set expire time operation on multiple keys?

Tags: redis

I want to set multiple keys with an expire time, but it seems I have to expire every keys one by one.Why do not Redis provide an operation just like "mset"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this operation is not so frequent and you can easily simulate it by:

- a server-side Lua script

or

- pipelining several expire commands

Whatever the chosen solution, it will only generate a single roundtrip to the redis server.

Comment: For those using `spring-data`, there is built-in support for pipelining - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline

Answer (score 6):

You can use one script as it.

```
EVAL 'for i, name in ipairs(redis.call("KEYS", "0*")) do redis.call("EXPIRE", name, 10); end' 0
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here a bit more? What is the purpose of the `"0*"`, and the `10`?

Comment: The "0*" is a wildcard to get all keys that start with value 0 and set 10 seconds to expire.